# C# VSTO-Powerpoint-TaskPanes in separate windows.

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I'm creating a VSTO for my company, and have ran across a interesting issue that I could use some help with. I will try to explain this to the best of my ability. I have the AddIn set up right now for it to create 2 customTaskPanes upon start up via Application.AfterNewPresentation events. And the ability to hide/show these based on user input from togglebuttons on the Ribbon.

Now when I fire up the first PowerPoint 2010 called "Presentation1" everything works great, I can show/hide the TaskPanes and everything inserts the way it should. Now then I open up a second template called "Presentation2"(to help keep things straight here) Everything works great again, I can show/hide the TaskPanes and everything inserts fine. If I go back to "Presentation1" the inserts and everything functions fine, but when I got to hide/show the TaskPanes it hides/shows them on "Presentation2". And if I create a "Presentation3" the same thing will happen but both "Presentation1" and "Presentation2" control "Presentation3" TaskPanes. And if I close the "Presentation2" and "Presentation3" the "Presentation1" buttons do not show/hide anything at all.

Code in the ThisAddIn

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
         Application.AfterNewPresentation += new PowerPoint.EApplication_AfterNewPresentationEventHandler(Application_AfterNewPresentation);
}

private void Application_AfterNewPresentation(PowerPoint.Presentation Pres)
{
        PowerPoint.Application app = Pres.Application;
        PowerPoint.DocumentWindow docWin = null;
        foreach (PowerPoint.DocumentWindow win in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Windows)
        {
            if (win.Presentation.Name == app.ActivePresentation.Name)
            {
                docWin = win;
            }
        }

        this.myWebForm = new SearchWebForm();
        this.myWebFormTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myWebForm, "Search ",docWin);
        this.myWebFormTaskPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
        this.myWebFormTaskPane.Width = 345;
        this.myWebFormTaskPane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(WebFormTaskPane_VisibleChanged);
    }

    private void WebFormTaskPane_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.searchButton.Checked = myWebFormTaskPane.Visible;
        if (Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.searchButton.Checked == true)
        {
            myWebForm.SearchForm_Navigate();
        }
    }
```

And then this is in the ribbon

```
    private void searchButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.WebFormTaskPane.Visible = ((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerPoint 2007, custom [task panes are shared across all presentation windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608620.aspx#ExcelAndPowerPoint). If you want to have separate task panes assigned to each presentation you need to handle the corresponding events (`WindowActivate`, `PresentationClose`, etc.). You would also need to manage a list of all the task panes that you've created so you can show/hide the appropriate one. This is actually a [well-known Outlook pattern frequently referred to in VSTO-world as **InspectorWrappers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608622.aspx) - or in your case a **DocumentWindowWrapper**.

This has been changed for Powerpoint 2010 and now each taskpane is associated with a specific window. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb608620(v=vs.100).aspx#WordAndInfoPath).

Your error is that `Globals.ThisAddIn.WebFormTaskPane` does not necessarily correspond to the current presentations task pane - you need to lookup the proper task pane in your managed list (*as mentioned above*). When you create a new task pane (`AfterNewPresentation`), add it to your [`CustomTaskPane`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) collection and provide a means of retrieving it.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{    
  private Dictionary<PowerPoint.DocumentWindow, DocumentWindowWrapper> pptWrappersValue =
            new Dictionary<PowerPoint.DocumentWindow, DocumentWindowWrapper>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction I have seen this link before and tried to work my way through the Outlook one but making the wrapper class work with powerpoint is where I keep getting hung up at due to their being no inspector in Powerpoint. I will try again thanks.

Comment: @KJones - glad to help you out! Please mark this as an answer so it can help future people who run into the same issue.

Comment: Alright I'm lost in translation from a few things from the Outlook to Powerpoint. Mainly in the wrapper class, such as adding the Close event. Which in PPT would be PresentationClose, but how do I specify which "inspector" to use as PPT event handlers will not accept any parameters. And the same with the ManagingRibbon as PPT doesn't seem to use this function either.

Comment: Take a look at the [`RibbonControlEventArgs.Control.Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol.context.aspx) which is the [`PowerPoint.DocumentWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.documentwindow.aspx) reference.For the close event, take a look at the [`PowerPoint.Presentation.DocumentWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.documentwindows.aspx) collection that is the existing event handler parameter. `DocumentWindow` = `Inspector` for translation purposes.