# C# VSTO-Powerpoint-TaskPanes in separate windows

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, ribbon

I have created a PowerPoint VSTO Addin with a custom Task pane - and a ribbon where a toggle button defines the display / hide Status of the custom Task pane. Basis for this was the Microsoft Walkthrough information for custom Task pane and synchronizing the Ribbon with the Task pane.
So fare everything works fine with the first PowerPoint window. I'm able to show the Task pane in the second and third PowerPoint window, but the toggle button on the ribbon only reacts to the last opened / created PowerPoint window and not to the Task pane displayed / hidded in the active PowerPoint window.

I've found another thread which explains exactly the same Problem here:
[C# VSTO-Powerpoint-TaskPanes in separate windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625466/c-sharp-vsto-powerpoint-taskpanes-in-separate-windows/47846110#47846110)

But I don't understand the answer neither I don't know how to implement a PowerPoint Inspector Wrapper.

I'm new in C# and just getting a keyword like "Inspector Wrapper" is to less for me. I already spend hours in searching the net but wasn't successfull till now.

Is there a chance to get a COMPLETE code example for PowerPoint how this works, what has to be done?

Code added:
I took the code from the General walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590.aspx and changed it with an Event for new presentations:

The code for the ThisAddIn.cs is as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace PowerPointAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private TaskPaneControl taskPaneControl1;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane taskPaneValue;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.AfterNewPresentation += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_AfterNewPresentationEventHandler(NewPresentation);
            //taskPaneControl1 = new TaskPaneControl();
            //taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add( taskPaneControl1, "MyCustomTaskPane");
            //taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
        }

        void NewPresentation(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation oPres)
        {

            PowerPoint.Application app = this.Application;
            PowerPoint.DocumentWindow docWin = null;

            foreach (PowerPoint.DocumentWindow win in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Windows)
            {
                if (win.Presentation.Name == app.ActivePresentation.Name)
                {
                    docWin = win;
                }
            }

            this.taskPaneControl1 = new TaskPaneControl();
            this.taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneControl1, "MyCustomTaskPane", docWin);
            this.taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
        }

        private void taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.Ribbons.ManageTaskPaneRibbon.toggleButton1.Checked =
            taskPaneValue.Visible;
        }

        public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane TaskPane
        {
            get
            {
                return taskPaneValue;
            }
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code trials with us

Comment: I took the code from the General walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590.aspx

Comment: Are you targeting 2007? Unless you are, the accepted answer says that the solution has to do with the `CustomTaskPane` collection, not `InspectorWrapper`s.

Comment: With 2013/2016 - and yes i see this but there is nowhere a complete code example which i could implement to see how it works and to be able then to adjust. Because of beginner it is very hard to understand the requirements or what has to be implemented related to the keyword custmtaskpane collection. Hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need a solution in Visual Basic (VB.NET):

**MyPaneClass**:

```vb
Public Class MyPaneClass
    Public Property MyWindow As PowerPoint.DocumentWindow

End Class
```

**ThisAddIn.vb**:

```vb
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        AddHandler Application.AfterNewPresentation, AddressOf AddNewCustomTaskPane
        AddHandler Application.AfterPresentationOpen, AddressOf AddNewCustomTaskPane
    End Sub


    Private Sub AddNewCustomTaskPane(ByVal pres As PowerPoint.Presentation)

        Dim myPane As New MyPaneClass()
        Dim myCustomTaskPane = CustomTaskPanes.Add(myPane, "Title of your pane", pres.Windows(1))

        myPane.MyWindow = pres.Windows(1)

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Ribbon1.vb**:

```vb
    Private Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles HSLABtn.Click

        Dim myPane As MyPaneClass = Nothing
        Dim myTaskPane As Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane = Nothing
        Dim activeWindow As PowerPoint.DocumentWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow

        ' Searching for a panel that belongs to the active window
        For Each taskPane As Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane In Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes
            myPane = TryCast(taskPane.Control, MyPaneClass)
            If myPane IsNot Nothing AndAlso myPane.MyWindow.Equals(activeWindow) Then
                myTaskPane = taskPane
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'Just to be on the safe side.
        If myTaskPane Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        ' Toggle visibility
        myTaskPane.Visible = Not myTaskPane.Visible

    End Sub
```

If you need to perform some actions to deactivate the panel when the document is closed, then add the following code to `ThisAddIn_Startup()`:

```vb
AddHandler Application.PresentationBeforeClose, AddressOf CloseTaskPane
```

And in `ThisAddIn.vb` add the code:

```vb
    Private Sub CloseTaskPane(ByVal pres As PowerPoint.Presentation, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

        ' Searching for a panel that belongs to the active window
        For Each taskPane As Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane In Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes
            Dim myPane As MyPaneClass = TryCast(taskPane.Control, MyPaneClass)
            If myPane IsNot Nothing AndAlso myPane.MyWindow.Equals(pres.Windows(1)) Then
                
                ' A code for deactivating the panel.
                ' ....
                ' myPane.Deactivate()

                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember the learning curve oh so well. Here's a sample that I believe addresses your issue. You need to link the task pane to the document. I relied on the naming scheme for new documents here, but a `DocumentVariable` would be a much better choice (they are discarded at the end of the current session). Add a variable to the presentation, store the task pane id in the control, and compare them to get the right task pane.

You need an XML ribbon (could probably use a Ribbon Designer but those are not as good). I removed some of the boilerplate and irrelevant code from this.

ThisAddIn.cs:

```
namespace PowerPointAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public static int counter = 0;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.AfterNewPresentation += Application_AfterNewPresentation;
        }

        private void Application_AfterNewPresentation(PowerPoint.Presentation Pres)
        {
            int count = ++counter;

            UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1("task pane " + count);
            CustomTaskPane ctp = CustomTaskPanes.Add(uc, "custom task pane " + count);
            ctp.Visible = true;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new Ribbon1();
        }
    }
}
```

Ribbon1.cs:

```
namespace PowerPointAddIn1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Ribbon1 : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public Ribbon1()
        {
        }

        public void toggleTaskPane(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool enabled)
        {
            var CTPs = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes;
            var pres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;

            foreach (var x in CTPs)
            {
                if (pres.Name.EndsWith(x.Title.Replace("custom task pane ", "")))
                {
                    x.Visible = enabled;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool isPressed(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            var CTPs = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes;
            var pres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
            foreach (var x in CTPs)
            {
                if (pres.Name.EndsWith(x.Title.Replace("custom task pane ", "")))
                {
                    return x.Visible;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ribbon1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="MyGroup"
               label="My Group">
          <checkBox id="mycheckbox" label="show task pane" onAction="toggleTaskPane" getPressed="isPressed" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

UsreControl1.cs (just has a label on it):

```
namespace PowerPointAddIn1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1(string labelValue)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label1.Text = labelValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris for your input - i will check this comming weekend. Maybe you have an idea - as you can see above I added the new task pane with the window object - I thought that this is the link to the current active window when it was created - and this was also what I saw in the window properties (presentation 1).
but as soon as I created a new presentation and with this event a new custom task pane with the current window also the first ctp got in window the new presentation (2) and not  the presentation 1 anymore. Why is this updated? Can this be avoided?

Comment: Chris, your hint with the document variable (in PowerPoint = Tags on presentation level) helped me - so I'm able now to compare CTP and Presentation.Tag and now I can show/hide CTP for each presentation individually with the same ribbon toggle button.
Next steps are to manage the CTP's when document was closed etc. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my results which works now for me (Thanks to Chris who gave me some valuable inputs). I do have a customtaskpane management which works for each presentation. The only Thing which is not yet implemented is if a user opens the document in a separate window (View / New Window). This one I don't know how to manage.
As fare as I can test it this works now.
here is the link to the whole solution: 
https://happypc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/roger_heckly_happy-pc_ch/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0426d40dc5df74d66ba42a3b928111ce8&authkey=Aa6yX6QWUnqXp1jcUfGveL8

Please be Aware - I'm beginner - so if you have feedback / inputs please let me know. For sure, some code could be written easier etc.